# Server Connection Error : IP adress is not available

Tags: ip

I use a web app deployed on an apache-like proprietary server to create my building automation system. I match ip settings of server  and network interface. But it gives such an error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esc5X.jpg)

And the computer network settings :

[ip settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcGrz.png)

So , to solve that, I entered those lines on command prompt :

> netsh winsock reset catalog
>
> netsh int ip reset reset.log

and restarted computer. It did not work. I would appreciate much your help. Thanks.

Comment: can you please show us the webserver network/IP configuration too ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5guvwpmhw1u45uk/Image%203.png?dl=0

Comment: thanks, and do you have multiple network interfaces ? i mean, this one is used on the same machine ? (it's not a virtual machine with specific settings etc ? )

Comment: Yes, it is on just a laptop with only one interface.